# Excel VBA - Add a value to an existing string in a cell at a cursor point

Tags: excel, vba

Cell already contains a value: e.g.
ABC 123 09.01.23

Looking to add a value to that existing string in a cell at a cursor point, i.e. if I put a cursor after ABC then run a macro, that produces date and time stamp, I'd like the result to be: ABC 09.01.23 10:12:15 123 09.01.23

But if I put a cursor at the end, I'd like a result to be: ABC 123 09.01.23 09.01.23 10:12:15

Running the below code does nothing when I put a cursor into the cell.  It only works when cell is selected, but no cursor activated in it.

```
Sub timeStamp()

Dim ts As Date

With Selection

.Value = Now
.NumberFormat = "m.d.yy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It cannot be done as no event can run when a cell is in edit and it will not know the position of the cursor.

Comment: To me this does sound like an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want the placement to be so arbitrary?

Comment: What's determining where you put your cursor? Use that and work it into your code.

Comment: How about just add it at the end in a new line, similar to Alt + Enter?

Comment: `Selection.Value = Selection.Value & Chr(13) & Format(Now,"m.d.yy h:mm:ss AM/PM")` But this will only work if the selection is not in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Sub Append_FU_Today()

ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & "Followed Up on - " & Now()

End Sub
```